# COUNTIFS Statement Issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, data-manipulation

I'm trying to create a countifs function to obtain information from another sheet and get a count based on if the data matches the conditions of multiple columns and cells within the same rows.

```
=COUNTIFS('daily delivery &  making Points'!$Z$5496:$Z$6253,”JO”, 'daily delivery &  making Points'!$AA$5496:$AA$6253, "Yes")
```

Tried a few variations of this but for some reason it just doesn't want to work.

It should read that if the first result is "JO" and the second is "Yes" then it counts 1.

Please help?

Comment: *it just doesn't want to work* is unclear. Your formula looks good. Does it return wrong result? Maybe calculation is set on manual?

Comment: In the absence of anything to go on, check for trailing spaces etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are using the correct `"`.  I noticed that it looks like you're using two different types.

Comment: Might just be a SO formatting change.  The apostrophes around "JO" and "Yes" are different though.

Comment: My comment was directed at your previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for your help, sadly the solution posted didn't work.
I rewrote the same formula and it seemed to work this time fine, not sure what was wrong but copied it down and won't need to analyze it further.

I will still vote up regardless.

This was the formula that worked.

```
=COUNTIFS('daily delivery &  making Points'!$Z$5496:$Z$6253,"JO",'daily delivery &  making Points'!$AA$5496:$AA$6253,"Yes")
```